# Python Referenced For Loop

Tags: python

I'm playing with `for` loops in Python and trying to get used to the way they handle variables.

Take the following piece for code:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=a
b[0]=6
```

After doing this, the zeroth element of both `b` and `a` should be `6`. The `=` sign points a reference at the array, yes?

Now, I take a `for` loop:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
for i in a:
    i=6
```

My expectation would be that every element of `a` is now `6`, because I would imagine that `i` points to the elements in `a` rather than copying them; however, this doesn't seem to be the case.

Clarification would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything in python is treated like a reference. What happens when you do `b[0] = 6` is that you assign the `6` to an appropriate place defined by LHS of that expression.

In the second example, you assign the references from the array to `i`, so that `i` is 1, then 2, then 3, ... but `i` never is an element of the array. So when you assign 6 to it, you just change the thing `i` represents.

http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html is an interesting read if you want to know more about the details.

Answer (score 5):

That isn't how it works. The for loop is iterating through the values of a. The variable i actually has no sense of what is in a itself. Basically, what is happening:

```
# this is basically what the loop is doing:
# beginning of loop:
i = a[0]
i = 6
# next iteration of for loop:
i = a[1]
i = 6
# next iteration of for loop:
i = a[2]
i = 6
# you get the idea.
```

At no point does the value at the index change, the only thing to change is the value of i.

You're trying to do this:

```
for i in xrange(len(a)):
    a[i] = 6 # assign the value at index i
```

Comment: "The variable i actually has no sense of what is in a itself" - This isn't exactly true, `i` is a reference to the values in `a` but assignment will change `i` to be a reference to something else, and integers are immutable so there isn't any way to change the OP's list by modifying `i` in a `for` loop.  But consider `a = [[1], [2]]` then `for i in a: i[:] = [6]`.  `a` will become `[[6], [6]]`.

Comment: @F.J. That is because the values of `a` are mutable types in themselves. It has nothing to do with the position in a, rather it has to do with the objects whether they are in a or no.

Comment: No argument there, I just wanted to clarify because a novice reader might interpret your statement as "it is impossible to modify a list by looping over its values", which isn't true when you have mutable values.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you said, "The = sign points a reference". So your loop just reassigns the 'i' reference to 5 different numbers, each one in turn.

Comment: I read your answer and smacked myself. It was so simple! Is there a way to make the for loop behave in the manner I want? (Definite Upvote - you strike to the heart of the matter.)